# Accessing parent properties inside relationship query

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

An example:

```
$passing_students = App\Exam::whereHas('students', function ($query) {
    $query->where('mark', '>=', $exam->pass_mark);
})->get();
```

I am interested in fetching all exams with students who passed however in the relationship query function I'm not sure how to access the parent model's properties such that I can complete the comparison. What should be in place of `$exam->pass_mark`?

Note that I'm looking for a solution that is done within the single query builder as I'm aware that this can be easily done in a separate foreach loop.

Comment: you can use `with` function for ORM relationship query.

Comment: @helen-che did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably instead of:

```
$query->where('mark', '>=', $exam->pass_mark);
```

you should use here:

```
$query->whereColumn('mark', '>=', 'exams.pass_mark');
```

Above `exams.pass_mark` is name of Exam model table (I assumed you use `exams` and column name from this table.